# How to center a button while creating it responsive with CSS

Tags: html, css, button, textbox, center

I'm using basic HTML, CSS and Javascript to create a simple web app. As I tried text-align: center and other CSS elements to center the button, I'm still having trouble.. I'm also trying to center a text inside the box center, but doesn't work for unknown reason. So far, I have used margin-left and margin-right to adjust the button but willing to know how to center it without going through all these hassle.

[image]

```css
.image {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.image img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image img:hover {
  border: solid 2px #1e88e5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image #mother img:hover {
  border: solid 2px #1e88e5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 43, 219);  
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.button:hover{
   background-color: #242424;
}
.button:active{
   background-color: #121212;
}

.button > span{
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Good Cop, Bad Cop</title>
  <style>
    .view-image img {
      margin-left: 90px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/landing.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/coach_selection.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img src="../IMAGES/Hamburger_icon.svg" alt="Character" height="35vh" />
      </a>

      <a href="settings.html">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <img src="../IMAGES/bootstrap-icons-1.3.0/person-circle.svg" alt="Profile" height="45vh" />
        </ul>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="image">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="dog-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/dog.png" id="dog" alt="dog">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="mother-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/mother.png" id="mother" alt="mother">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="soldier-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/military.png" id="soldier" alt="soldier">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="teacher-button" class="btn btn-light">
        <img src="../images/teacher.png" id="teacher" alt="teacher">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button" id="button-confirm">
      <span>Confirm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="view-image" style="display:none;">
      <img src="" width="150" height="150" />
      <div class="button" id="button-other"><span>Other</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom">
    <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="grid">
          <div class="bot-nav-img">
            <a href="Journal/journal_main.html">
              <img src="../IMAGES/bootstrap-icons-1.3.0/book-fill.svg" alt="Journal" height="40vh" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="bot-nav-img">
            <a href="landing.html">
              <img src="../IMAGES/bootstrap-icons-1.3.0/house-door-fill.svg" alt="Home" height="40vh" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="bot-nav-img">
            <a href="goals.html">
              <img src="../IMAGES/bootstrap-icons-1.3.0/table.svg" alt="Goals" height="40vh" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest way to create a perfect centre alignment in css is with flexbox.

The general pattern is, give the parent element that needs it's children centered a `display: flex;`, a `justify-content: center;`, and a `align-items: center;`

For your code, get rid of the all the `text-align`. Then to the `.button` class, which is already `display: flex`, add `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`

The span element with your text is a child of the button, so it will now become centered. The span element itself will not need any CSS properties to help it center.

```
.button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(43, 43, 219);  
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to just add your `button` code outside the `.image` class and add `margin` to the `button` like

```
.button { 
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
```

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/av9fn6tp/

Comment: Excellent! Working perfectly thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me.

```
.button {
    display : flex;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0px auto 0px;
}
```